# "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')" in Dicord.js v14

Tags: json, discord.js

```
const {SlashCommandBuilder} = require("discord.js");
const json = require("../sql.json")



const objId = 9

const filteredObj = json.filter((obj) => obj.id === objId)[0]
const name = filteredObj.name
const age = filteredObj.age
const id = filteredObj.id




module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("id")
    .setDescription("Make id check"),
  async execute (client, interaction){
    await interaction.reply({content: `name: ${json.name}\nage: ${json.age}\nid: ${json.id}`});
},
};
```

I have a discord.js v14 code searching json file

But i am getting this error:

"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"

How can ı fix that?

Comment: `json` is your entire json file, did you mean to use `filteredObj.name` or `name`?

Comment: ı mean filteredObj.name.In json file there is a name,age and id

Comment: Can you provide the full error message? It error will either be the `filteredObj.name` or `json.name` - I'd assume the first. so that means `json.filter((obj) => obj.id === objId)[0]` doesn't find a value